# Why is Poisson distribution's expected value not on the curve's maximum

Tags: probability, expected-value, poisson-distribution

For a Poisson distribution of $Poisson(\lambda=5)$ I have a curve like this:
[image]

If the expected value for a Poisson distribution is its rate parameter $\lambda$, then why isn't the maximum on the curve also 5? Doesn't expected value mean the most likely value?

Comment: The expected value (aka mean) does not necessarily equal the most likely value. (By the way, the most likely value is called the **mode**.) You may find https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229779/expected-value-vs-most-probable-value-mode/229789 helpful.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Ahh I see. Then what is the significance of expected value?

Comment: @StevenOh you literally can google that

Comment: The expected value is essentially the value that would occur "on average" -- if you were to repeatedly sample values from the distribution and take the running average, the running average would converge to the expected value of the distribution. For example, if you kept rolling a standard die repeatedly, you would find that the average of your rolls would tend to $3.5$ (which is the expected value of the die). Note that $3.5$ is not even a possible value of a die roll, so the expected value does not even have to be a possible value (let alone the most likely).

Comment: I asked a similar question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210475/why-two-modes-for-a-poisson-distribution-with-lambda-an-integer

Answer (score 3):

To have mean = mode you need a symmetric distribution. Try with a poisson with $\lambda =10$ or more and you will have $\text{argmax}(x) =\lambda$

Answer (score 2):

This phenomenon is not particular to a Poisson distribution. It's true whenever the distribution is skewed.

Which of the three "averages" you use in any particular application depends on the context.

[image]